# How to click a image button in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click an image button on the below link.
https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm
The button name is "Get Data". I tried to click the button using selenium in many ways but I could not

```
WebElement buttonClick = driver.findElement(By.className("getdata-button")); 
buttonClick.click();
```

Comment: What have you tried and what exception/error do you get? Is the problem `getting` the element or the `clicking` part?

Comment: *...I tried to click the button using selenium in many ways...*. Where is  your code?

Comment: problem is with getting the element

Comment: WebElement buttonClick = driver.findElement(By.className("getdata-button"));                                                                        
       buttonClick.click();

Comment: Your code seem to be correct. Share exception log

Comment: @Raghuvaran, how is going? Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried below Code and it worked well for me

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper_btm']/div[1]//input[3]")).click();
```

Apply above code or else provide me Exception Message that you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript executor to directly call the function that is associated with the 'Get Data' button click. Here function 'validateInput()' is called on button click event. Refer below:

```
driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm");
JavascriptExecutor scrExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
scrExecutor.executeScript("validateInput()");
```

This will simulate the click on this button.